# Reference to multiple models at onces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reference, mongoid

Quick scenario:

```
@employment = Employment.new
@company.employments << @employment
@person.employments << @employment
```

Here @employment is referenced in @company and @person, in different steps. Because of that @employment is saved 2 times.

But I have to do something if @employment is new record only. But because it is saved 2 times, @employment.new_record? returns false in 2nd referencing.(i.e while referenced_in @person)

So can't @employment can be referenced in both @company and @person in one step?

Answer (score 1):

This is a classical has_many :through association covered in the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association). There's a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many) available as well. The reference from Company and Person to employment should be the other way around.

```
Person n<->1 Employment 1<->n Company
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really not a good idea to try and replicate has_many :through with Mongoid. The code will get very messy and you'll have all kinds of bugs.